# Does every docker container directly present only a shell?

Tags: docker

Does every docker container directly present only a shell ?

I have a python image:

```
$ sudo docker image list
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
python              2.7-slim            48e3247f2a19        10 days ago         120MB
```

I originally thought it presents Python to me.

But I can't run python commands directly in the container:

```
$ sudo docker run 48e3 print("hello")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

and I can run commands directly in the container, just as in a shell:

```
$ sudo docker run 48e3 ls
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
$ sudo docker run 48e3 python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

Answer (score 3):

How the container executes depends on how it was built.  In the builder's `Dockerfile` there may be `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` options.

For example, here is a container that never calls `/bin/sh`.

First, the program we want to run.  I've written it in `go` just because it's easy to demonstrate.

```
$ cat small.go 
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello")
  fmt.Print("You entered ")
  fmt.Println(os.Args[1:])
}

$ go build small.go
```

Now the instructions for building the container:

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM scratch
ADD small /
ENTRYPOINT ["/small"]

$ docker build -t small .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.642MB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 2/3 : ADD small /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6171cecbf91b
Step 3/3 : ENTRYPOINT ["/small"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 14af8187a035
Successfully built 14af8187a035
Successfully tagged small:latest
```

And now running the container:

```
$ docker run --rm small some options passed
Hello
You entered [some options passed]
```

In fact this container only contains one file, the `small` program and nothing else!  No shell, no libraries, nothing.

Now the docker image you're looking at will drop into `python` if you run it correctly and don't pass any parameters

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:2.7-slim
Python 2.7.16 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:57:44) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

If we inspect the image, we can see...

```
$ docker inspect python:2.7-slim
...
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"python2\"]"
            ],
```

So we can see it was built with the `CMD` option in `Dockerfile`.  This tells it the *default* command to run if no other command is passed to the `docker run` call.

So with this container, it will run `python` if not told to run anything else.

Which means we can do fun things like

```
$ echo 'print("hello")' | docker run --rm -i python:2.7-slim
hello
```

Comment: Could we remove the first line `FROM scratch`?

Comment: @flow2k Please open a new question for this; it doesn't belong in comments.

Comment: Actually, I posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330046/is-from-clause-required-in-dockerfile a few days ago. Feel free to weigh in if you have additional input. Thanks.